Billing for a Firebase Storage rule that access Firestore
I have a Firebase Storage rule that looks like this:
    match /mycoll/{pagenum}/picture.jpg {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if request.auth != null
           && firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/mycoll/$(pagenum)).data.owner == request.auth.uid; // CHECK OWNER
        allow delete: if false; // DISALLOW DELETE OPERATION
    }

as you notice only the write part makes a query to check for a match of the owner in Firestore.
My first question is:

will I get charged for a read in Firestore If I only try to download (read) the file picture.jpg from Firebase Storage?

My second question is:

will I get charged in case of a failed write with reason = auth is null (first check before the && that reads in firestore)



will I get charged for a read in Firestore If I only try to download (read) the file picture.jpg from Firebase Storage?

No.  Your read rule doesn't do anything with Firestore, so will will incur no read costs.

will I get charged in case of a failed write with reason = auth is null (first check before the && that reads in firestore)

No.  Security rules short-circuit booleans expressions and don't continue to evaluate sub-expressions when the entire expression is already known.
See:

Firestore rules, using short circuit to squeeze out reads
Firestore - security rules: are multiple reads in OR connection and will evaluate "lazily"?
Does Firestore security rules return early?


I don't understand. According to the short-circuiting logic then I should not be charged for the read because I never get to the line that does the get() in firestore. What am I missing?

I misread the first part.  Your read rule doesn't cost anything at all in terms of reads.
